# How do I use hadoop streaming cmdenv with Oozie?

Tags: workflow, hadoop-streaming, oozie

I have a Hadoop streaming job with the parameter:

```
 -cmdenv TEXT_DIR=cachetextdir
```

How do I specify this in an Oozie workflow?

(I am assuming I can point to cachetextdir in Oozie with:

```
 <archive>hdfs://localhost:54310/user/vm/textinput/cachetextdir.tar.gz#cachetextdir</archive>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like:

```
            <streaming>
            <mapper>[MAPPER-PROCESS]</mapper>
            <reducer>[REDUCER-PROCESS]</reducer>
            <record-reader>[RECORD-READER-CLASS]</record-reader>
            <record-reader-mapping>[NAME=VALUE]</record-reader-mapping>
            ...
            <env>[NAME=VALUE]</env>
            ...
        </streaming>
```

from [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.2.4_Syntax) will do the job.

UPDATE: yes it does:

```
    <streaming>
      <mapper>python smspipelineHadoop.py</mapper>
      <env>TEXT_DIR=cachetextdir</env>

    </streaming>
```